# ImageColorAt does not return alpha from ImageCreateTrueColor

Tags: php, gd

Trying to do some image manipulation I discover that `imagecreatetruecolor()` seems to only be 24-bit. I go through the motions needed for `imagecopyresampled()` to preserve the alpha from an image.

```
$bottles = imagecreatefrompng("bottles.png");
$output = imagecreatetruecolor(32, 32);
imagecolortransparent($output, imagecolorallocatealpha($output, 0, 0, 0, 127));
imagealphablending($output, true);
imagesavealpha($output, false);
imagecopyresampled($output, $bottles, 0, 0, $type*32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32);
```

The resulting image looks like this: [image: one of many sprites in bottles.png]

I then want to do some special manipulation where I need to know the alpha channel of each pixel, however when I perform the following:

```
for($y = 0; $y < 32; $y++)
{
    for($x = 0; $x < 32; $x++)
    {
        $c = imagecolorat($output, $x, $y);
        $rgb = imagecolorsforindex($output, $c);
        echo $c."\n";
        print_r($rgb);
```

`$c` returns `16777215` for all parts of the picture that doesn't have a color in it (or rather all parts that still have a white color under that transparency), and `$rgb["alpha"]` shows zero. However, should I change `$output` to `$bottles` then `$c` returns `2130706432`. That looks more like a 32-bit number, and indeed `$rgb["alpha"]` shows a variety of numbers.

So if `imagecolorat()` does not return an alpha from `imagecreatetruecolor()`, how do I find out its alpha values? I have changed the `imagealphablending()` and `imagesavealpha()` combo around (true+true, true+false, false+true, false+false) just before `imagecolorat()` but it still returns a 24-bit number.